# How to end iteration of DFS

Tags: c, algorithm, graph, depth-first-search

I'm trying to implement a DFS on a graph in C but i'm struggling with how to backtrack when I get to node from which there are no more unvisited members available.
I have already tried all possible solutions that I can only think of, without any success.
Thanks in advance for help.

```
void dfs_iter(int** graph, int* marks, int gsize, int i, NODE** stck)
{
    push_stack(st, i);
    marks[i] = 1;
    printf("%d ", i);

    while (!test_stack(*stck)) {
        int current = data_stack(*stck);
        int k;
        for (k = 0; k < gsize; k++) {
        if ((graph[current][k] == 1)) {
            if (marks[k] == 0) {
                push_stack(stck, k);
                marks[k] = 1;
                printf("%d ", k);
                break;
            } else {
                int l, is_route = 0;
                for (l = k; l < gsize; l++) {
                    if (graph[current][l] == 1 && !marks[l]) {
                        is_route = 1;
                    }
                }
                if (!test_stack(*st) && !is_route)
                    pull_stack(st);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the graph that I'm trying to do DFS on:

```
0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 1 0
0 1 0 0 0
1 0 1 0 0
```

Comment: You should be marking the visited nodes inside the while loop. See [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search#Pseudocode). Look at `DFS-iterative`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost I would strongly recommend you to start from a typical implementation of DFS, which is recursive.

```
1  procedure DFS(G,v):
2      label v as discovered
3      for all edges from v to w in G.adjacentEdges(v) do
4          if vertex w is not labeled as discovered then
5              recursively call DFS(G,w)
```

This helps visualising how DFS actually works. Note that **the first thing you do when visiting a node is mark it as visited.** To keep track of visited/not visited nodes you can, for example, create an array, in which every node from the graph has one field. If that field is 0 - it has not been visited. If 1 - it is already visited (of course this is just one possible implementation). Then note, that you never go to visited nodes again (meaning if you are in node X and Y is a neighbour of X, then if Y is marked as visited you do not visit it again, just go check the next neighbour.) Then check out the iterative algorithm pseudocode:

```
1  procedure DFS-iterative(G,v):
2      let S be a stack
3      S.push(v)
4      while S is not empty
5            v ← S.pop() 
6            if v is not labeled as discovered:
7                label v as discovered
8                for all edges from v to w in G.adjacentEdges(v) do
9                    S.push(w)
```

Same here: you only visit v if it is not marked as visited yet.

Comment: Thank you very much Byakuya, I've corrected the code, it does work now! Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

Just keep track of visited nodes in an array. Then whenever the new node from the stack is already visited then do nothing and continue.

Comment: If I remove the "else" part from the "if (marks[k] == 0)" [which is the array which keeps true/false values of visited vertices], it just keeps hanging at e.g. 0 vertex if I start searching from vertex 3. I'm struggling with the pull_stack() function which seems not to be in the right place.